# How to avoid providing security credentials in Alfresco OpenLDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, alfresco, openldap, jboss-eap-6, alfresco-ldap

We have to provide Alfresco and jBoss web application users authentication with openLDAP. 
The OpenLDAP is configured so, that there is now need to provide any credentials to read openLDAP directory.
In case of jBoss configuration I am not providing these credentials with bindDN and bindCredential tags and authentication is working.
In case of Alfresco that is not the case, if I do not provide  ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal and  ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials, I have synchronization error in log:

```
2019-02-15 10:58:04,466 ERROR [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization aborted due to error
org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationException: 01150001 Failed to authenticate, username or password is wrong. User name:cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=com Reason [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

So ldapsearch retreives the openLDAP directory without providing any credentials:

```
ldapsearch -x -h 10.0.1.15:389 -b "dc=some,dc=ua"
```

jBoss standalone-full.xml:

```
<login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="sufficient">
    <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://10.0.1.15:389"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
    <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=Users,dc=some,c=ua"/>
    <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Users,dc=some,c=ua"/>
    <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
    <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="false"/>
    <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="1"/>
    <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
    <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
</login-module>
```

Alfresco alfresco-global.properties

```
authentication.chain=alfinst:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap
ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=false
alfresco.authentication.authenticateCIFS=false

ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.synchronization.active=true
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=uid=%s,ou=Users,dc=some,dc=ua
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://10.0.1.15:389
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Admin

ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=uid\=someUser,ou\=users,dc\=some,dc\=ua
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=12356

ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=Users,dc\=some,dc\=ua
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=Users,dc\=some,dc\=ua

ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(&(objectclass\=posixGroup)
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=posixGroup)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(objectclass\=inetOrgPerson)
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=inetOrgPerson)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))

ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=modifyTimestamp
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=uid
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=o
ldap.synchronization.groupDisplayNameAttributeName=displayName
ldap.synchronization.groupType=posixGroup
ldap.synchronization.personType=inetOrgPerson
ldap.authentication.java.naming.read.timeout=0
ldap.synchronization.userAccountStatusProperty=ds-pwp-account-disabled
ldap.synchronization.disabledAccountPropertyValue=true
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=userHomesHomeFolderProvider
ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
ldap.synchronization.enableProgressEstimation=true
ldap.pooling.com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug=fine
synchronization.autoCreatePeopleOnLogin=true
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
synchronization.syncOnStartup=true
synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
synchronization.externalUserControl=true
synchronization.externalUserControlSubsystemName=ldap1
```

Is it possible to avoid providing OpenLDAP credentials in alfresco-global.properties?
Alfresco Community (Build: 201612)
jBoss EAP-6.4

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on with Alfresco: Authentication and Synchronization. Authentication against OpenLDAP can happen without a credential because it binds using the user's credential.

Synchronization, however, happens in batch in the background. The synchronization job that runs needs a credential to authenticate with OpenLDAP so it can query for users and groups created or modified since the last check. If you don't provide a credential it would mean your OpenLDAP directory would have to be wide open, which is surely not what you want.